# Coffee script access to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am new to javaScript, coffee script, jQuery and the UI tech in general. I am trying to accomplish really simple thing - read a value from the input field but so far with no luck. My code is pretty simple:

```
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags" value="Hello">
    </div>
```

From coffee script I am trying to read the value as follows:

```
jQuery ($) ->
    $field = $('.ui-widget input')
text=$field.val
alert #{ text }
```

But so far with no luck, but contrary via $field.val("Bye") works just fine.

Could someone please put some shed on that?

Thx

Comment: You need to out the `val` and `alert` calls into that callback function as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter less function calls require parentheses.

```
text=$field.val
```

Is translated to

```
var text;

text = $field.val;
```

Notice that you are getting a function reference to `val`

Adding the parans:

```
text=$field.val()
```

Becomes

```
var text;

text = $field.val();
```

Returning the result of the function rather then the function itself.